# NOT IN does not produce same results as NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, three-valued-logic

These are rather basic statements. I have a list of graphics which are linked to items in another table. I want to check how many of the graphics are not in use and can theoretically be deleted.

So first I used the NOT IN clause:

```
SELECT [GraphicNr]
      ,[Graphicfile]
  FROM [dbo].[Graphic]
 WHERE graphicnr NOT IN (SELECT graphicnr FROM dbo.Komp)
```

Which gave zero results, which seemed weird to me. After rewriting it to a NOT EXISTS, I got about 600 results:

```
SELECT [GraphicNr]
      ,[Graphicfile]
  FROM [dbo].[Graphic] a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT graphicnr FROM dbo.komp b WHERE a.GraphicNr = b.GraphicNr)
```

So I guess I don't really have a problem, since the second statement works, but to my understanding, shouldn't the first one give the same results?

Comment: The `(select graphicnr from dbo.Komp)` sub-query returns a null value. `NOT IN null-value` returns 0 rows. Lesson (learned): avoid `NOT IN (sub-query)`, do `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, though I don't really understand why NOT IN NULL returns 0 rows by default. It's not a statement I've used much before, so I didn't know that NOT IN was this inferior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Comment: `select graphicnr from dbo.Komp where graphicnr is not null` would do it, but see answers below to understand _why_.

Answer (score 3):

`NOT IN` with a subquery has strange behavior.  If any row in the subquery returns a `NULL` value, then *no* rows are returned.  This is due to following the strict semantics of `NULL` (which means:  "I don't know if they are equal").

`NOT EXISTS` behaves as you would expect.  For this reason, I recommend never using `NOT IN` with a subquery.  Always use `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

That because of `NULL` value returned from `subquery` :

```
SELECT [GraphicNr], [Graphicfile]
FROM [dbo].[Graphic]
WHERE graphicnr NOT IN (SELECT graphicnr FROM dbo.Komp)
```

This would produce `no records` or `no rows affected` because of `graphicnr not in (null)` which is not desired output.

So, the `NOT EXISTS` would not work as the way the `IN` clause or `NOT IN` work. It behaves differently then `IN` or `NOT IN` clause.

However, you can prevent this by using `IS NOT NULL` filter in `subquery`. But the recommended way is to use `NOT EXISTS` instead.